# Xamarin forms - Query an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi Im trying to query an array. Here is my class where my array is created:

```
public class json_object
    {
        [JsonProperty("bs")]
        public Bs[] bs { get; set; }
    }

    public class bs
    {
        public string titulo { get; set; }
        public string pp { get; set; }
        public string direccion { get; set; }
        public string idE { get; set; }
        public string sigue { get; set; }
        public string telefono { get; set; }
        public string horarios { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public string promedio { get; set; }
        public string foto { get; set; }
        public string estrella_1 { get; set; }
        public string estrella_2 { get; set; }
        public string estrella_3 { get; set; }
        public string estrella_4 { get; set; }
        public string estrella_5 { get; set; }
        public string seguidores { get; set; }
        public string uno { get; set; }
        public string dos { get; set; }
        public string tres { get; set; }
        public string cuatro { get; set; }
        public string cinco { get; set; }
    }
```

The im trying to is for example, send an string "idE" and search for an element in the array that contains that string in it's value "idE" and then return the object. Is it possible? I've read that this can be achieved with Where<> but im still investigating how to do it.

P.S: I just want to return a single object, since the string I send, is specifically the one contained in the value "idE" of my array.

Answer (score 2):

this is just basic C#, and has nothing to do with Xamarin

this will return all the matching objects

```
var match = myobj.bs.Where(x => x.idE.Contains(search));
```

to return only the first match

```
var match = myobj.bs.First(x => x.idE.Contains(search));
```

Comment: I first make a conection to my backend to obtain 14 string to then use them all along my app. Suppose that in a different class, I need to get 14 strings to send them to a class with a constructor that receives 14 arguments, doing this thing you mentioned. Will you recomend it to me in terms of optimization? Since I need to do this in different classes along the app.

Comment: if you have multiple classes that need to access the same set of data, I'd consider storing them in a static class or singleton that is accessible throughout your project

Comment: yeah, but it varies with the string that I need to search for in that momment